# Error: distutils.errors.DistutilsExecError: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1 running cython

Tags: python, numpy, cython

I'm trying to call a cython file .pyx from a python file .py but I find the error:

```
fatal error: 'numpy/arrayobject.h' file not found #include "numpy/arrayobject.h"
```

followed by:

```
distutils.errors.CompileError: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

The file .py has the following import statements:

```
import pyximport; pyximport.install()
from testing_cython import Cython_Class
```

And the import statements in the cython files are the following:

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
from cpython.array cimport array, clone
```

I cannot understand how to solve the problem. I'm using MacOSX 10.13 with anaconda3 as python interpreter.
Can anyone help me?
Thanks in advance